# I can not determine the type of Array

Tags: java, actionscript-3

My client (As3) send to my server (Java) this array to a function:

```
{2={y=16.0, x=17.0}, 1={y=17.0, x=17.0}, 0={y=18.0, x=17.0}}
```

But I can not determine the type.

I tried: String[], Object[], ect..

Server-side:

```
 public void MaSuperFonction(Object[] $path){ ... }
```

Client-side :

```
this.groupedList[0] = {x:this.startX,y:this.startY};
this.groupedList[1] = {x:this.startX,y:this.startY};
this.groupedList[2] = {x:this.startX,y:this.startY};

    var path = this.groupedList[0];
      if(this.groupedList.length > 1)
      {
         var i = 1;
         while(i < this.groupedList.length)
         {
            path = path.concat(this.groupedList[i]);
            i = i + 1;
         }
      }
    this.nc.call('MaSuperFonction',path);
```

But without success.

```
Method MaSuperFonction with parameters [{2={y=16.0, x=17.0}, 1={y=17.0, x=17.0}, 0={y=18.0, x=17.0}}] not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather say that it is a `Map<Integer, Point>>`, where the `Point` class can be declared as:

```
class Point {
    private Double x;
    private Double y;
    // getters/setters
}
```

You should understand that it is a sequence of key=value pairs, which can't be represented by arrays (each cell of which contains only a single element).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your client is sending the 2-d double array , see below sample code on how to create 2-d double array and iterate over it :-

```
public class SOArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] a = new double[3][2];
        a[0][0] = 16.0;
        a[0][1] = 17.0;
        a[1][0] = 18.0;
        a[1][1] = 19.0;
        a[2][0] = 20.0;
        a[2][1] = 21.0;

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<2; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also like above code with some modification accept it, in 2-d double array on server side.